How to capture the onChange event inside a form using Nuxt 3 and Shadcn
I have a form with 4 fields, what I want is to be able to change the label of the second field based on the value of the first field and enable/disable the last field based on whether the third field is checked or not but no matter what I try I'm unable to capture the change event of the field. Here's my code
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { type IDropdown } from "../interfaces/dropdown.interface";
import * as z from "zod";
import { useForm } from "vee-validate";
import { toTypedSchema } from "@vee-validate/zod";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";
import { Select } from "@/components/ui/select";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { RadioGroup } from "~/components/ui/radio-group";
import {
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";

const isIndividualPerson = ref(true);

const sector: IDropdown[] = [
  { label: "FORESTAL", value: "F" },
  { label: "DESECHOS", value: "D" },
  { label: "AGRICULTURA", value: "A" },
  { label: "PROCESOS INDUSTRIALES", value: "PI" },
  { label: "ENERGIA", value: "E" },
];

const formSchema = toTypedSchema(
  z
    .object({
      personType: z.enum(["individual", "juridica"], {
        required_error: "Por favor, elija el tipo de persona",
      }),
      name: z.string({ required_error: "Por favor, ingrese su nombre" }),
      projectSold: z.boolean().optional(),
      projectSoldDoc: z.instanceof(File).optional(),
    })
    .superRefine(({ projectSold, projectSoldDoc }, ctx) => {
      if (projectSold) {
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
          message: "Por favor, adjunte un archivo",
          path: ["projectSoldDoc"],
        });
      }
    })
);

const personTypeChanged = (value: string) => {
  console.log("Persona tipo:", value);
};

const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
  validationSchema: formSchema,
});

const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values) => {
  console.log("Form submitted!", values);
});
</script>

<template>
  <form class="w-2/3 space-y-6" @submit="onSubmit">
    <FormField name="personType" v-slot="{ componentField }" type="radio">
      <FormItem class="space-y-3">
        <FormLabel>Tipo de persona</FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
          <RadioGroup
            class="test"
            v-bind="componentField"
            @change="personTypeChanged"
          >
            <FormItem>
              <FormControl>
                <RadioGroupItem value="individual" />
              </FormControl>
              <FormLabel>Persona Individual</FormLabel>
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
              <FormControl>
                <RadioGroupItem value="juridica" />
              </FormControl>
              <FormLabel>Persona Juridica</FormLabel>
            </FormItem>
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage />
      </FormItem>
    </FormField>

    <FormField name="name" v-slot="{ componentField }">
      <FormItem>
        <FormLabel>
          <span v-if="isIndividualPerson === true">
            Nombre del titular del proyecto completo
          </span>
          <span v-else>Nombre de la empresa</span>
        </FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre"
            v-bind="componentField"
          />
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage />
      </FormItem>
    </FormField>

    <FormField name="projectSold" v-slot="{ value, handleChange }">
      <FormItem>
        <FormLabel>Vendidas</FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
          <Checkbox :checked="value" @update:checked="handleChange" />
        </FormControl>
      </FormItem>
    </FormField>

    <FormField
      name="projectSoldDoc"
      v-slot="{ value, handleChange, handleBlur }"
    >
      <FormItem>
        <FormLabel>Adjuntar archivo</FormLabel>
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            type="file"
            placeholder="Seleccione un archivo"
            accept="image/*, application/pdf"
            @change="handleChange"
            @blur="handleBlur"
          />
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage />
      </FormItem>
    </FormField>

    <Button type="submit"> Submit </Button>
  </form>
</template>

<style></style>

The personTypeChanged is never called, I have tried several things but nothing seems to work.

Have you tried values from useForm ?
